# Semantics/grammar conflict between English and JAX-B

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, jax-rs, resteasy

The following DTO is for emcapsulating a bunch of Employee records to be transmitted between service provider and service requester.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement (name="employees")
public class EmployeeList {
  private List<Employee> employee;

  public List<Employee> getEmployee() {
    if (employee==null)
      employee = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    return employee;
  }

  public void setEmployee(List<Employee> employee) {
    this.employee = employee;
  }
}
```

The above DTO declaration would produce the following XML

```
<employees>
  <employee id="1234" ...... />
  <employee id="1236" ...... />
  ....
</employees>
```

The problem arises when I wish to get the list of employees.

```
public void showEmployees(EmployeeList employeeList) {
    List<Employee> employees = employeeList.getEmployee();
    dothedo(employees);
}
```

Notice that the function is not getEmployees but getEmployee, because the field is employee rather than employees.

So, I change the DTO to:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement (name="employees")
public class EmployeeList {
  private List<Employee> employees;

  public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
    if (employee==null)
      employee = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    return employee;
  }

  public void setEmployee(List<Employee> employee) {
    this.employee = employee;
  }
}
```

So that I now would getEmployees

```
List<Employee> employees = employeeList.getEmployees();
```

The trouble with putting the plural into the DTO is that following XML would result, which is not acceptable. I don't even think that RestEasy run-time would not croak due to naming conflict between root element and child element.

```
<employees>
  <employees id="1234" ...... />
  <employees id="1236" ...... />
  ....
</employees>
```

So, what is your recommendation, in order to have DTOs that are intuitive in the English language (plurality items bearing plural name), and that the XML output is also intuitive (singular items should have singular tag names).

Is there a way I could re-architect my list DTOs to avert this semantic conflict? If no, do you think it is crucial enough an issue that a next version of jax-b should treat it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use @XmlElement(name = "employee") on your employees property.

See also @XmlElementWrapper - not necessary in this case (since your class is the "employees" wrapper) but would be necessary if you were modelling something like a "company" with "employees".